# const parameter problems

Tags: c++, constants

```
#include <iostream>

void f(const  int * & p)
{
    int i =0;
    i = p[0];
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int * p =new int[1];
    p[0] =102;
    f(p);
    return 1;
}
```

The gcc compiler gives error for this code:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:16: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const int*&’ from expression of type ‘int*’
prog.cpp:5: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void f(const int*&)’
```

But if I change the "f" function into

```
void f(const  int * const & p)
```

Everything is ok. Can somebody explain why const behaves this way? thanks.

Comment: hi. It's always helpful to post the error message you see in such cases. Please can you do so?

Comment: http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyHowCppConst.html check out this reference it explains why you are getting these errors

Comment: I've added the error message as produced by gcc4.3.4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Going from `int*` to `const  int*` requires creating a temporary `const int*` pointer and binding the reference `const int*&` to that temporary.

The Standard forbids doing that creating of a temporary for non-const references. You therefor need to make the reference const as you did your fix.

This is because non-const references mean "I want to change the argument that the caller passes using that reference parameter". But if the caller needs to convert their argument and ends up passing a temporary, the point of the reference is for naught, and so the Standard deems it an error to try and pass the temporary.

Answer (score 1):

If the first conversion (`int *` to `const int * &`) were allowed, then you could write an evil function like this:

```
const int really_const[] = {1,2,3};

void evil(const int * & p)
{
    p = really_const;
}

int main()
{
    int not_const[3];
    int * p = not_const;
    evil(p);
    p[0] = 0;  // Whoops: modifying a const object
}
```

The second conversion is fine, since it prevents the function from modifying the pointer in this way.

Comment: Unless the conversion were defined to go via `const int*`, in which case `p = really_const` would modify a temporary, not the `p` variable from `main`. Then `evil` would be better titled `confused`, since it would modify a temporary that's immediately destroyed, and the user would be left wondering where their changes went.